# Evaluating Maxwell Relations with Constant Entropy for Arbitrary EOS

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, gas

If you were given a Gas Equation of State, whether that be Ideal, van der Waals, Redlich-Kwong, or some more complex EOS, and you needed to evaluate a Maxwell Relation such as $\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial v}\right)_s$, how do you typically enforce that constant-entropy condition?

Ignoring the particular EOS, we can obtain the following through the [Cyclic Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product_rule#:%7E:text=The%20triple%20product%20rule%2C%20known,derivatives%20of%20three%20interdependent%20variables):
$$ \left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial v}\right)_s \left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial s}\right)_p \left(\frac{\partial s}{\partial p}\right)_v = -1$$
Knowing the following Maxwell Relations:
$$ \left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial s}\right)_p = \left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial p}\right)_s $$
$$ \left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial T}\right)_s = - \left(\frac{\partial s}{\partial p}\right)_v $$
We can rearrange and substitute to obtain:
$$ \left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial v}\right)_s = \left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial v}\right)_s \left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial T}\right)_s $$
Once again however, we are still left with a constant-entropy condition to enforce, and no partial derivatives in terms of pure EOS variables, i.e. $\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial T}\right)_v$ or $ \left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial v}\right)_p $. In these situations, what do you do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$dS=\frac{C_V}{T}dT+\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_TdV=\frac{C_V}{T}dT+\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_VdV$$
Also,
$$dS=\frac{C_P}{T}dT+\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial P}\right)_TdP=\frac{C_P}{T}dT-\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_PdP$$So, at constant S, $$\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial V}\right)_S=-\frac{T}{C_V}\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_V$$and$$\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_S=\frac{C_p}{T}\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial V}\right)_P$$

Comment: Thank you. This process makes sense in hindsight, but is there a way to notice that you need to make these steps? I attempted to use the exact differential for $$ ds(p, v) = \left( \frac{\partial s}{\partial p} \right)_v dp + \left( \frac{\partial s}{\partial v} \right)_p dv $$ but was unsuccessful in obtaining a useful relation as above. Do you always need to include $T$ as part of an entropy exact differential? How would this change if we were evaluating at constant $h$, for example, for the Joule-Thompson coefficient $$ \mu_{JT} = \left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial p} \right)_h = ? $$

Comment: the JT coefficient is pretty straightforward.  What does you equation in s, p, and v look like for an ideal gas?  That might give you an idea what to do.

Answer (score 0):

The state of a thermodynamic system is uniquely defined by (usually) 2 variables which can be any of the properties of the system, i.e. $p,V,T,S$, etc. Consequently the properties of the system, which are functions of the state, can be expressed as functions of any combination of 2 other properties, i.e. $p(V,T), p(S,T), p(V,S),$ etc. The Maxwell relations relate the various partial derivatives of the functions in different coordinate systems, for example $(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T})_S = (\frac{\partial S}{\partial p})_V$ relates partial derivatives of $V(T,S)$ and $S(p,V)$.

To calculate the general expression $(\frac{\partial x}{\partial y})_z$ you need to express $x$ as a function of $y$ and $z$, $x = x(y,z)$, and take the partial derivative.

Take the internal energy of an ideal gas as an example: To calculate something like $(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V})_p$ you take $U(p,V) = \frac32pV$ to get
$$\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)_p = \frac32p$$
and to calculate $(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V})_T$ you take $U(V,T) = \frac32nRT$ to get
$$\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)_T = 0$$

To compute something like
$$\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial V}\right)_S = \left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial V}\right)_S\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial T}\right)_S$$
you need $p(V,S)$, $T(V,S)$, and $p(T,S)$, although in practice its usually not that easy to express things as functions of entropy.

Comment: Not all pairs are good *globally*, some are good only *locally*, e.g., $(p,V)$ is a pair of mechanical parameters and do not necessarily form good thermodynamic parameters, see my comments to https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/785369/in-a-carnot-engine-how-does-the-heat-flow-from-the-heat-reservoir-to-the-engine

Comment: @hyportnex I looked over your comments and I see that my first paragraph is not true in general, so thanks for pointing that out. That being said, I would think that certain coordinates only need to be valid locally to compute the associated partial derivatives at a given point, right? What do you think

Comment: I did not mean to say that locally good variables are not enough for your proof, in fact I think that the differential identity in question needs only locally good variables, I only added my comment to warn you that the 1st sentence in your answer maybe understood in a broad sense, and it is quite a common error, also in textbooks, to assume that one can just pick any coordinate pairs globally. This error in *physics* is at the heart of all criticisms lobbed against Caratheodory and his *mathematically* precise axiom system.