# Measurability of internal energy in thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, work

I am reading **H.B. Callen - Thermodynamics**, and I am having a hard time understanding a lot of its logic. One example is in the first chapter **(chapter 1, sections 5, 7, 8)**, where he talks about measurability of internal energy.

He starts saying that the state of a system (in simplified conditions, such as no charge, no chemical reactions, no gravity etc.) is given by the composition $N$ (number of moles of the chemical species, assume a constant single component), the volume $V$ and the internal energy $U$, which consists in the macroscopic manifestation of microscopic interactions and movement.

Then he says, that energy cannot be measured, only differences in energy can. In particular Joule proved that any two thermodynamical states can be connected with an adiabatic purely mechanical process where $\Delta U = W$ (this mechanical work can be measured and is the energy difference). Then he proceeds to define heat in a process connecting the same two states as $Q = \Delta U - W'$ (the work will be different but measurable). You measure the energy difference via an adiabatic process, you measure the work done in the current process and you get the exchanged heat.

**The problem is this is circular logic to me**:

Start from $A=(U_A,V_A,N)$ move non-adiabatically to $B=(U_B,V_B,N)$ (you do not know what $U_B$ is as you cannot measure the heat exchanged yet, $Q=ΔU−W'$). You know that your system has changed as you clearly did something to it (say the volume changed and you measure it and you measure $W'$), now according to Joule you are able to connect adiabatically $B$ to $A$ (or the viceversa), this means that you design a process that brings back your state to the one you had before, the volume from $V_B$ to $V_A$, and that you do enough work $W$ to cover the energy difference. Now, how much work do you need to do (adiabatically)? You can't say as you do not know what $U_B−U_A$ is.

Comment: > *if I do a non-adiabatic process from $A$ to $B$, how can I be sure that I reached the actual $B$ and not some $B'$* By assumption, you do a process ending in $B$. Are you asking how this is done in an actual experiment? You make sure the final state is an equilibrium states, and has values of $T,P,V$ equal to those that $B$ defines.

Comment: Ok, but at this point, there is nothing except energy, composition and volume in Callen's theory. So the "state" is just that. Of course if you make the energy a state function, and you change your definition of state (that you just gave in the preceding section by the way) it makes sense.

Comment: Callen is a nice book, but don't take axiomatic efforts too seriously. Physics is not mathematics and is not based on axioms.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am trying to find some material on thermodynamics that has the fewest tacit assumptions and I was suggested this book. I probably need to change my approach.

Comment: Please give the specific references in Callen so we can see the context.

Comment: To quote from section 1-5 of the 2nd edition: *"In all systems there is a tendency to evolve towards states in which the properties of are determined by intrinsic factors and not by previously applied external influences. Such simple terminal states are, by definition, time independent. They are called equilibrium states"* What is your problem with this statement?

Comment: I am saying that you have to "assume" that you reach the same state that you previously adiabatically reached to be able to define the heat exchanged in that process. This is circular logic (given only the theory of Callen's chapter 1, sections 7, 8). If you are able to say "ok, I have reached the same state as before" in order to define internal energy, when the state itself is made of internal energy something is missing.

Comment: This is not circular logic, it is axiomatization, just like Euclid with his undefined points and lines and the axioms describing them, say, two points can always be connected by a line and two non-parallel lines always meet at one point. Joule did not prove anything experimentally that in all adiabatic processes starting from one state a unique state is reached by external work, Instead, he measured some work and temperature variations in a series of water tank experiments equipped with a paddle wheel stirrer. That is not a proof of anything in an axiom system, that is a beautiful experiment.

Comment: If you introduce temperature as part of your state (and remove energy, considering it a dependent variable) then of course it is not circular. You have to first establish that state $(U,V,N)$ and state $(X,Y,Z,\dots)$ for whatever variables you choose, describe the same system. If Callen said that a state was $(V,N,T)$ and that energy was a state function then all works, but this is not really done in the first chapter so I was confused.

Comment: you are right that a $V,N,T$ axiom system could have been just as good but that would have broken the mathematical symmetry of the setup that is based on external "mechanical measurements" and mechanical work differences. This is Caratheodory's way that is elegant but is shown and known to be not as general as a temperature based "axiomatization", see Sommerfeld's problem here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/785369/in-a-carnot-engine-how-does-the-heat-flow-from-the-heat-reservoir-to-the-engine